# what does this expression/function mean?

Tags: fourier-transform

This is a really short question i was just wondering what the expression

$F_x(\sin^2(\pi k_0 x))(k)$

means is it just a function f that is $sin^2(\pi k_0x)$ or is it something else?

Comment: where have you seen this

Comment: My guess (without any context to go on) is that the expression $F_x(\sin^2(\pi k_0 x))(t)$ means $g(t)$, where $g$ is the Fourier transform of the function-of-$x$ that is $\sin^2(\pi k_0 x)$.

Comment: it is like calculate the fourier transform of this